# Every derived table must have its own alias. How to add alias to sql code

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans, xampp

here is my sale table in Database

[image: sale table]

```
ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("SELECT TotAmount FROM (SELECT DISTINCT SONumber From sale ");
```

I need to get Total Amount of TotAmount column for DISTINCT SONumber

Comment: You need to clarify one thing: assuming there are several rows in `sale` with equal `SONumber`, which one of the `TotAmount` you want? Minimum? Maximum? Average? First or last by some date? The sum of all of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need a simple `group by`:

```
SELECT   SONumber, SUM(TotAmount)
FROM     sale
GROUP BY SONumber
```

Comment: that might be true, but it's not an answer to the question that was asked.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this, with following assumptions:

- TotAmount is a sum of all Amount values over the same `SONumber`
- The above is maintained to be true across all possible mutations of your data

Then, the principal query which would get you the `TotAmount` is this:

```
select distinct
  SONumber, TotAmount
from sale
```

*(Seriously consider refactoring your database so there is no `TotAmount`, or it is stored elsewhere though, to avoid duplicating the data, thus wasting space)*

---

If second of my assumptions does not actually hold, but first one is true, then it is this query:

```
select
    SONumber, sum(Amount) as TotAmount
from sale
group by SONumber
```

*(The second query is also a perfect example why you didn't need a `TotAmount` column in the first place: it is easily computed, and it will not require any maintenance due to additions and removals of rows in that table.)*

Comment: Thank you very much buddy.. that's true..there i no use with TotAmount column. thank you again